# Where can I ask questions about some online total country Internet connection monitoring site of codes?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have asked this question:

[Is there any site for seeing Iran internet connection in real time [closed]](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63808/is-there-any-site-for-seeing-iran-internet-connection-in-real-time?noredirect=1#comment113050_63808)

But it got flagged as off-topic in the [networkengineering.stackexchange.com](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) forum.

One comment said:

> Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly
>   off-topic here, as are questions about networks you do not directly
>   control, web sites, applications, and protocols above OSI layer

But where can I ask this question?

Comment: Not all questions are suitable for the StackExchange model, and even if a given question _is_ "stackable" in theory, there may not be an appropriate stack for it - StackExchange isn't _quite_ universal, yet. You should always check the Help Center for a given stack to find out what's on- or off-topic for that stack.

Comment: And note: your question is really broad, and unclear. It is similar to asking "how do I build a skyscraper?" or something. Focus on breaking down your problem into (much) smaller parts. Unless you do that, you won't be able to get helpful answers, no matter where you ask.

Comment: The newest site specifically for Iran is: https://filter.watch/ - opening next month.

Comment: Maybe you could ask on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/. Or on Reddit.

Comment: Your question reads as an recommendation question, a shopping question. Those have proven to be less valuable and therefor practically banned across the SE network. Try chat.

Comment: What do you mean by "codes" (in the title)? Some software?